Relative particle
Relative particle in Hebrew is "asher" meaning "who", "whom", "which", what". Some examples:

min haadamah asher ererah yahweh
because of the ground which the Lord has cursed (Genesis 5:29)


zor owt haberit asher ani noten
This is the sign of the covenant which I make (Genesis 9:12)


wayasem sham et haadam asher atsar
he put the man whom he had formed (Genesis 2:8)

This particle is missed in this verse:

Hen avdi etmak
Behold! My Servant whom I uphold  (Isaiah 42:1)

Literally: my servant I uphold
My question is: are there other verses of the Bible where this particle is not mentioned in hebrew text and but is translated into English with it?

Iike this verse Isaiah 42:1. The word "asher" (whom) isn't in hebrew text, but is in English

I am sure there are plenty.  English and Hebrew are very different with very different grammars.  The translators must accommodate such differences to (1) make sense, and (2) observe the grammatical rules in the receiving language.  What you point out is common.  There is a second example in the same verse of Isa 42:1.

There are many more examples in the same chapter of Isa 42 such as in V5 (four times), V7, V10, V17 (twice), V19, etc.

I open Strong's Exhaustive Concordance to WHO (or whom, which, or what) and look at the lines with no number following. In each of these cases there is no Hebrew word being translated. Where the number is 834, asher is being translated. Where a different number is listed, a different word is being translated.
